# Finding the derivative of an equation

Tags: calculus, surfaces, volume

I am currently doing an investigation in which I am required to design the dimensions of a juice box (can be cube/cuboid) which has the least possible surface area that can hold 200 ml of juice.

I have combined these surface area and volume formulas:

$$V = lwh$$

$$A = 2(lw + lh + wh)$$

(V = volume. A = surface area. l = length. w = width. h = height.)

...

To make this:

$$A = 2(lw + \frac{200}{w} + \frac{200}{l})$$

(the V was substituted with the volume, 200 ml)

...

So, now that I have an equation (which I don't know if it is correct), I would like to find the least possible value for A, the surface area. If I am not mistaken, I will need to find the derivative of the equation using differential calculus. But, what then? Is that already the least possible surface area?

Apologies, I am new to the concept of calculus, so please inform me if I have done anything wrong in my calculations.

Comment: Your calulaions look correct thus far. All that is left is optimizing your equation $A=2(lw+\frac{200}{w}+\frac{200}{l})$, which will give you the dimensions with the minimum surface area

Comment: **Hint:** The smallest surface area of a cuboid for a given volume is a cube.

Answer (score 1):

Let us admit that we do not know the answer (that is to say that *the smallest surface area of a cuboid for a given volume is a cube* as calculus commented).

You properly arrived to $$A = 2\big(lw + \frac{200}{w} + \frac{200}{l}\big)$$ Since you want $A$ to be minimum, you need to set its derivatives with respect to the variables $l,w$ equal to $0$ (think about the bottom of a valley).

So, $$A'_l=2 \left(w-\frac{200}{l^2}\right)=0\tag 1$$ $$A'_w=2 \left(l-\frac{200}{w^2}\right)=0\tag 2$$ From $(1)$, $w=\frac{200}{l^2}$. Plug this in $(2)$ to get $$l-\frac{l^4}{200}=l\big(1-\frac{l^3}{200}\big)=0$$ I suppose that you will accept to forget the case $l=0$. So, what remains is $l^3=200$ which corresponds to $l= \sqrt[3]{200}$. Back to $w$, you will get the same value as well as for $h$.

So, we face a cube of side equal to $ \sqrt[3]{200}\approx 5.84804$.

You could change the specific $200$ to any $V$ and get a cube of side dimension $ \sqrt[3]V$.